# JDO - datanucleus - HSQL error

Tags: jdo, hsqldb, datanucleus

For my current project I have to use HSQL-JDO. I am writting sample application to check how this work. If I am using HSQL with jdbc (without any orm) my code run fine. But with JDO I am getting "socket creation error"

`[Server@187a84e4]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
[Server@187a84e4]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
[Server@187a84e4]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
[Server@187a84e4]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
[Server@187a84e4]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
[Server@187a84e4]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
[Server@187a84e4]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
[Server@187a84e4]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
JdbcOdbcDriver class loaded
registerDriver: driver[className=sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver,sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver@a13f991]
DriverManager.initialize: jdbc.drivers = null
JDBC DriverManager initialized
registerDriver: driver[className=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver,org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver@44e06940]
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:8974/test_db")
    trying driver[className=sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver,sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver@a13f991]
*Driver.connect (jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:8974/test_db)
    trying driver[className=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver,org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver@44e06940]
SQLState(08000) vendor code(-80)
java.sql.SQLException: socket creation error
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1158)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:444)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.(RDBMSStoreManager.java:264)`

Here is the code in main

        `Server server = new Server();
        server.setAddress("localhost");
        server.setDatabaseName(0, "test_db");
        server.setDatabasePath(0, "test_db");
        server.setPort(8974);
        server.setTrace(true);`

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass","org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory");
    properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName","org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL","jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:8974/test_db");
    properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName","SA");
    properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword","");
    properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword","");

    properties.setProperty("datanucleus.autoCreateSchema","true");
    properties.setProperty("datanucleus.validateTables","false");
    properties.setProperty("datanucleus.validateConstraints","false");

    PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(properties);

    PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx=pm.currentTransaction();

    tx.begin();
    pm.makePersistent(new Session("aniruddha"));
    tx.commit();

    Query q = pm.newQuery("SELECT FROM "+Session.class.getName());

    List<Session> sessions = (List<Session>)q.execute();
    //Iterator<Session> iter = sessions.iterator();

    for(Session s : sessions){
        System.out.println(s.getSESSION_ID()+" : "+s.getSESSION_USERNAME());
    }
```

Here is the bean that I want to persist

`@PersistenceCapable
public class Session {
    private Session(){
        // Default constructor required by jdo
    }
    public Session(String session_username){
        SESSION_USERNAME = session_username;
    }`

```
public long getSESSION_ID() {
    return SESSION_ID;
}
public String getSESSION_USERNAME() {
    return SESSION_USERNAME;
}
public void setSESSION_ID(long sESSION_ID) {
    SESSION_ID = sESSION_ID;
}
public void setSESSION_USERNAME(String sESSION_USERNAME) {
    SESSION_USERNAME = sESSION_USERNAME;
}


@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.INCREMENT)
private long SESSION_ID;
private String SESSION_USERNAME;
```

}

Comment: A google search for that exception and HSQL will give lots of information

Comment: if I put connection string something like "jdbc:hsqldb:file:test_db". It works. But if connection string is something like "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:8974/test_db" gives me "socket creation error"

Comment: It looks to be something wrong with my configuration. I did google, but nothing found that resolve problem yet.

Comment: Comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637433/jdo-datanucleus-hsql-error#comment13813125_10637433 works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If server mode doesn't work then you haven't started the HSQLDB server. Works for me with either form, either URL or file. I start a server from the command line exactly as per the HSQLDB docs.

With your API calls for Server, you seem to be missing calling "server.start()". Either way the problem is in HSQLDB server startup, not DataNucleus access.

Comment: Thanks for replying. My problem resolved. I wasn't starting server.